# override C# TabControl add method

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I would like to create a custom version of the TabControl so that when a new TabPage is added I can ensure some custom processing is performed.

The question is how do I override the TabPages.Add() method to achieve this?

thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the custom version which inherits from the TabControl, and has a `public new void Add(string)` method. But if anyone casts your control back to the TabControl, they would go around your logic. You could try creating a custom control which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control and expose all the methods of a private TabControl, modifying the Add method as needed. This would give you much more control.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, you cannot override `Add()` method of `TabPageCollection` class. What you may try is to subscribe to `TabControl.ControlAdded` event in hope that it will be raised when a `TabPage` (which is essentially a `Control` as well) will be added.